# How to show sorted list by overall completion in Pootle

Tags: python, html, django, pootle

Hi I am new to Django and working on Pootle project.

I would like to sort by Overall completion by default in the pootle index page. 
for example, http://pootle.locamotion.org/ lists the languages and sorted by names. you can click sort buttons to see sort by completion. but I would like to show this list sorted by completion whenever load a page.

in pootle/local_apps/pootle_app/templates/index/index.html,

```
 <table class="sortable">
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans 'Language' %}</th>
                <th>{% trans 'Overall Completion' %}</th>
                <th>{% trans 'Last Activity' %}</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in languages %}
            {% ifnotequal item.total 0 %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'even' 'odd' %}">
                <td class="language">
                        <a href="{% filter l %}/{{ item.code }}/{% endfilter %}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
                <td>
                        <div class="sortkey">{{ item.transper }}</div>
                        <div class="graph" title="{{ item.completed_title }}" dir="{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}rtl{% else %}ltr{% endif %}">
                        <div class="translated" style="width: {{ item.transper }}px"></div>
                        {% if item.fuzzy %}
                        <div class="fuzzy" style="{%if LANGUAGE_BIDI%}right{%else%}left{%endif%}: {{ item.transper }}px; width: {{ item.fuzzyper }}px"></div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if item.untrans %}
                        <div class="untranslated" style="{% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}right{% else %}left{% endif %}: {{ item.transper|add:item.fuzzyper }}px; width: {{ item.untransper }}px"></div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </td>   
                <td>{{ item.lastactivity }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endifnotequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

item.transper is the key that I want to sort by.

and this is how item and language is defined:

```
def get_items(request, model, get_last_action, name_func):

    items = []                                                                                          
    if not check_permission('view', request):                                                           
        return items

    for item in model.objects.iterator():                                                               
        stats = item.getquickstats()                                                                    
        stats = add_percentages(stats)                                                                  

        lastact = get_last_action(item)                                                                 
        items.append({
            'code': item.code,
            'name': name_func(item.fullname),
            'lastactivity': lastact,                                                                    
            'trans': stats["translatedsourcewords"],                                                    
            'fuzzy': stats["fuzzysourcewords"],                                                         
            'untrans': stats["untranslatedsourcewords"],                                                
            'total': stats["totalsourcewords"],                                                         
            'transper': stats["translatedpercentage"],
            'fuzzyper': stats["fuzzypercentage"],                                                       
            'untransper': stats["untranslatedpercentage"],                                              
            'completed_title': _("%(percentage)d%% complete",
                                 {'percentage': stats['translatedpercentage']}),
            })
    items.sort(lambda x, y: locale.strcoll(x['name'], y['name']))
    return items        

def getlanguages(request):
    def get_last_action(item):
        try:            
            return Submission.objects.filter(translation_project__language=item).latest()
        except Submission.DoesNotExist:
            return ''   

    return get_items(request, Language, get_last_action, tr_lang)
```

what should I change this so that I see sort by Overall Completion by default?

thank you so much for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
items.sort(lambda x, y: locale.strcoll(x['name'], y['name']))
```

to

```
items.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x['transper'], y['transper']))
```

(This works well with the builtin `cmp` function because the `transper` fields are converted to `int`s by the [`nice_percentage`](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/Pootle/local_apps/pootle_misc/util.py) function, which is called as part of `add_percentages`)

If that doesn't produce the order you wanted, simply switch objects `x` and `y`.

---

If instead you need to sort it in the template (it's typically a bad idea to mess with third-party apps' source code), you can use [the `dictsort` filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort):

```
{% for item in languages|dictsort:"transper" %}
```

Again, if that's not the order you wanted, use [`dictsortreversed`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed).

Comment: thanks eternicode!! {% for item in languages|dictsortreversed:"transper" %} works! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The latest development version of Pootle, to become Pootle 2.2, now remembers which column you have selected to sort on.  So a page reload will now remember the order you last used.